# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imblearn.keras' or 'imblearn.tensorflow'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, imblearn

I want to import "balanced_batch_generator" into my Jupyter Notebook (I am using Tensorflow 2.0.0). I have tried

`from imblearn.keras import balanced_batch_generator`

`from imblearn.tensorflow import balanced_batch_generator`

However, I get the following errors, respectively:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imblearn.keras'`

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imblearn.tensorflow'`

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Which version of imblearn do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first install imblearn in command prompt, for example with Anaconda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn
```

Comment: I have already done this (first with Conda and then with pip install) and restarted my kernel both times but still get the same errors

Comment: Do your other imports work? Eg. try conda install numpy. Are you sure you have installed the imblearn to the same environment as Jupyter Notebook lives? I have tested this command and it works.